# Extract Data from Delimited string in mySql

Tags: mysql

I have a string which is an input to mysql Stored procedure. The string contains options for multiple choice questions.

**Sample String = "Managed code is the code that is compiled by the JIT compilers.~False^Managed code is the code where resources are Garbage Collected.~False^Managed code is the code that runs on top of Windows.~False^Managed code is the code that is written to target the services of the CLR.~False^"**

Each option has two columns i.e. OptionText and IsCorrect. The columns in same options are separated by **"~"** while the rows are separated by **"^"**. 
I want to insert each of these options into options table. I am confused as to how do I differentiate between two different delimiters in **MySql stored procedure**.

Comment: maybe its better if you post the actual stored procedure

Comment: if you're using php for the processing of the data you can use `explode()` on the "^" delimiter, and then `foreach` explode on the "~" delimiter, so you'd get an array element per row, and then as children, you'd have the columns in the same options